# How can I resolve labview 1386 error with thorlabs VI?

Tags: labview

I'm trying to use LabView to operate a ThorLab CS235CU camera. However, so far I haven't had any success using LabView to operate it, despite searching the provided thorlabs and national instruments documentation and google for an answer all week. I started by trying ThorLab's VIs that came with their software, but anytime I run a script it returns the following error:
[Error 1386 has occurred at Invoke Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VCWs.png). In the provided "simple image aquisition" VI, this error occurs at 3 locations [(steps 2, 3, and 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEg1x.png) before deleting the rest of the script, if run with execution highlighted. National Instruments has 3 suggested fixes on their website: unblocking DLLs manually, which seems unrealistic given I don't know what is causing this error; running LabView as an administrator, which I had been doing from the beginning and didn't help the issue; and creating a configuration file, which I tried but did not work. I put it in C:\ProgramFiles\National Instruments\LabView 2020 as well as C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\National Instruments\LabView 2020, but the error still occurs. I'm very new to using LabView and couldn't begin to explain why this error is occurring, so anyone that can or knows how to help, please do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't set up the ThorLabs driver properly one way or another. Often it is the manufacturer's installer that must be run first (with LabVIEW turned off) and eventually you'll find the according driver/dll wrapper VIs (also referred to as LabVIEW-Driver) in some arcane subdirectory like `<Program Files>\ThorLabs\<Product>\Drivers\Labview\...`

It might make sense to copy that directory to your `myProject\drivers\` Folder and the simple image acquisition.vi to something like `myProject\examples` and work your way from there. Also make sure you're using LabVIEW 32bit since few third-party drivers come in 64bit.